# Android: many activities on single screen?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, activitygroup, android-fragments

I'm creating my first app for Android device and I was faced with a challenge... I want to create fixed bottom bar on every screen of my application (something similar to bars from [tunein radio](https://market.android.com/details?id=tunein.player)).

However I do not know how to make bars which are fixed on every activity (bar do not load when new activity is loaded but is permanent on every app screen). I do not want to `<include>` my bars in every activity (I've tried this solution but my bars were loading with activity).

Is it possible that this is Activitygroup and only middle activity is changing? If so how can I do that?

PS. 
What book or tutorial do you recommend ;-)?

[tunein radio bottom and top bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8I3k.jpg) image #1

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [fragments api](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html). It perfectly fits your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately fragments API are available only on Android 3.0 :( so it doesn't fit my needs :(

Comment: There is a library, that lets you use it for android 1.6 and higher. It is available through SDK Updater (SDK Setup) with label «Android Compatibility package».

Answer (score 0):

Look at ViewFlipper. It lets you manage multiple views. You'd have one activity that would watch your button bar and flip views in response to buttons.

Comment: What about BACK_BUTTON? Should I override BACK_BUTTON handling in my activity and create own "view stack" for viewflipper :>?